# Returning string and int from same method

Tags: c#

```
public static int getInfo(string info)
    {
        string inputValue;
        int infor;
        Console.WriteLine("Information of the employee: {0}", info);
        inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        infor = int.Parse(inputValue);
        return infor;

    }
```

In the above code, how can I get the name(string) and salary(int) of a person? Specifications are that I need to call the method twice for the information retrieval.

Comment: So you want your method to return either a string or an int?

Comment: Use C#7 + tuples: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-tuples.

Comment: This screams XY problem (If you don't know what that means, Google it; I don't have a link handy on mobile). What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Thank you guys. I have done it with another way by explicitly converting string into in main method.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass it separately or better if you create a class which holds of info and the salary

```
 public static int getInfo(string info,int salary)
```

or create a class,

```
 public class MyInfo
    {
        public int info { get; set; }
        public int salary { get; set; }

    }
```

and the method signature goes as,

```
 public static int getInfo(MyInfo info)
```

If you want to return both string and int , better to change the method signature as of type class **`MyInfo`**

```
 public static MyInfo getInfo(MyInfo info)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants his method to _return_ the information.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet ok edited as it is. 2 more to get gold in c# ! :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan 2 more for gold! Jealous! Good luck, you'll get it fast

Comment: I cant use the classes for this particular case as the specifications says that i need method to be called twice and get the name and the salary out of one method.

Comment: @PrashantBhandari 1 Method will not return a different value type each time (generics as exception). You can get 2 values from 1 method though

Comment: @PrashantBhandari what specificiation? who suggested?

Answer (score 4):

You could make it return a tuple with both values like this:

```
internal Tuple<int, string> GetBoth(string info)
{
    string inputValue;
    int infor;
    Console.WriteLine("Information of the employee: {0}", info);
    inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
    infor = int.Parse(inputValue);
    return new Tuple<int, string>( infor, inputValue );
}

internal void MethodImCallingItFrom()
{
    var result = GetBoth( "something" );
    int theInt = result.Item1;
    string theString = result.Item2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For returning multiple values from a method we can use Tuples or (DataType, DataType,..).

Tuples are readonly. As a result assigning values is possible only via constructor at the time of declaration.

Below example is using multiple data types as return type. Which is both read and write enabled.

```
    public (string, int) Method()
    {
        (string, int) employee;
        employee.Item1="test";
        employee.Item2=40;

        return employee;
    }
```

You can call the above method in your main code, as shown below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        (string name,int age) EmpDetails = new Program().Method();
        string empName= EmpDetails.name;
        int empAge = EmpDetails.age;

        //Not possible with Tuple<string,int>
        EmpDetails.name = "New Name";             
        EmpDetails.age =  41;
    }
```

However, the best practice is to use class with properties, as mentioned in above answers.

Comment: I agree using a class with properties is the best answer, but I would have loved this (and still do) about 20 years ago when I was just figuring this out... This answer is Sweeter than YooHoo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in `.Net 7`

The method:

```
public (int, string) Returning2()
{
    int a = 10;
    string s = "ahsan ullah";
    return (a, s);
}
```

Call it from another function:

```
int x = Returning2().Item1;
string ss= Returning2().Item2;

Console.WriteLine(x + " " + ss);
```

`Item1` indicating `int` and `Item2` indicating `string`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string eName, totalSales;
        double gPay, tots, fed, sec, ret, tdec,thome;
        instructions();
        eName = getInfo("Name");
        totalSales = getInfo("TotalSales");
        tots = double.Parse(totalSales);
        gPay = totalGpay(tots);
```

}

```
public static string getInfo(string info)
    {
        string inputValue;
        Console.WriteLine("Information of the employee: {0}", info);
        inputValue = Console.ReadLine();

        return inputValue;

    }
```

This is what was required. Could have done with other tricks mentioned by you guys. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just return a String array with a size of 2? at the first (array[0]) there is the string and at the second (array[0]) there is the int...

```
public static string[] GetInfo (string info)
```

I hope I understood your question right ^^

Comment: i could have done this using TryParse with if else, but the case is that I need to call the method twice. :(

Comment: u can also make 'string stringname + Convert.ToString(int intname);'

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a person class and read name and salary

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Salary {get; set;}
}
```

and your function will be:

```
public static Person getInfo(string info)
{
    string inputName;
    string inputSalary;

    Console.WriteLine("Information of the employee: {0}", info);

    Console.WriteLine("Name:");
    inputName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Salary:");
    inputSalary = Console.ReadLine();

    Person person = new Person();
    person.Name = inputName;
    person.Salary = int.Parse(inputSalary);
    return person;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want one method to return different types of information, then I would use generics:

```
public static T GetInfo<T>(string name);

// This can be called as following:
string name = GetInfo<string>("name");
int salary = GetInfo<int>("salary");
```

There's one problem, though: `Console.ReadLine` returns a `string`, while our method could return any type. How can it convert a string to its 'target' type? You could check `T` and write custom logic for all types you want to support, but that's cumbersome and brittle. A better solution is to let the caller pass in a little function that knows how to transform a string into a specific type:

```
public static T GetInfo<T>(string name, Func<string, T> convert);

// This can be called as following:
string name = GetInfo<string>("name", s => s);
int salary = GetInfo<int>("salary", int.Parse);
```

Now how do you implement that method?

```
public static T GetInfo<T>(string name, Func<string, T> convert)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter " + name);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    return convert(input);
}
```

A few notes:

- Type parameters are often just named `T`, but I find it useful to give them more descriptive names, such as `TInfo`.
- The `<string>` and `<int>` parts can be left out in the second example, because the compiler has sufficient information to infer their types.
- I've left our error handling to keep the examples short and simple. In production code, you'll want to come up with a strategy to handle invalid input, though.